# Helper class in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm familiar with basic java but I'm very new to Spring. Previously I worked in php Laravel. I'm sorry if I sound dumb. I wanted to know if there's any way to declare and handle **Helper** methods in **Spring framework** like **Laravel**?

Edit:

```
public class Helper {
    publin int help() {...}
}
```

What I wanted was to call help() without Helper object or class name (considering the help() method is static). I simply wanted to call help() from anywhere in the project like

```
public class X {
    public void genericMethod() {
        int i = help(); //If it is posssible
    }
}
```

Any type of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a method without having an object, the method needs to be static.

```
public class Helper{
    public static void help(){}
}
```

You can then call it from anywhere in the same project by adding an import to the Helper class and writing `Helper.help()`. Or, you can add a static import to `Helper.help` and just write `help()`. All of this is explained [in the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html). It is not possible in Java to have global project-wide imports that can be called from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question but I think you are talking about having custom Utility classes. To have a Helper class you can write it using public static methods.

```
public class Helper {
  public static help() {
// insert helpful things here
}
}
```

That way you can access it from any class by calling Helper.help().

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be more clear. What I wanted was to call help() without Helper object or class name (considering the help() method is static). I simply wanted to call help() from anywhere in the project like int i = help(); [If it is posssible]